# JQuery/HTML5 : Organisational Chart, how to delete a node properly with this pluggin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, algorithm, tree

I want to do an organisational chart but I have some issues...
I use the JorgChart plugin (http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/jorgchart-a-plugin-for-creating-interactive-organization-charts-with-jquery/)

So here is the thing:

- I managed to do the double-click event to change the name of the node and to plug correctly this plugin.
- I managed to do a personalize context menu to add/remove a node.
- When I delete a node (and not a leaf) there is no problem, the node becomes grey and loses his name; but when I want to delete a leaf, the 'node' disappears but the 'blackline' stays...

And I don't know how I can manage to make disappear theses lines in the same time...

This is what the delete function looks like:

```
    /* line 346 */ 
    function removeNode() {


        /* The node is desactivated, we put it in grey. */
        lastClicked.addClass("nodeDeleted");

        var $tr = lastClicked.closest('tr');

        if(!lastClicked.hasClass("expanded")) {

            $tr.html(" ");

            /* We do the difference between the fact that the node disappared*/
            console.log("We removed for real the node: "+lastClicked.html().trim().substring(0,14));

        } else {

            /* And the fact that we just put the none in grey. */
            console.log("We desactived the node: "+lastClicked.html().trim().substring(0,14));
        }

        /* We erase the name of the node. */
        lastClicked.html("");
    }
```

It has been tested on IE11, Chrome and Firefox but it maybe have some problems on Safari.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ndt02yjc/1/

Result for now: http://jsfiddle.net/ndt02yjc/embedded/result/

Thank you very much in advance,
Cheers !

Comment: Salut Valentin, peux tu modifier ton jsfiddle en incluant correctement les css / js ? Tu ne dois pas mettre de Head dans le bloc html, les références se mettent dans le menu de gauche: voir http://jsfiddle.net/ndt02yjc/1/ (mais il me manque ton script organization.js, à moins que cela soit ce que tu as copié dans le bloc js aussi ?

Comment: organization.js est copié collé dans le bloc JS et le main.css dans le bloc css :) le but est de pouvoir modifier facilement le JS et d'avoir un rendu visuel sur les modifications :)

Comment: Ok donc ca va, juste il faut nettoyer la partie html, mais je l'ai fait dans le lien que je t'ai mis précédemment. Je regarde pour ton problème de suppression

Comment: Juste pour être sûr: que veux-tu précisément par rapport au fonctionnement actuel? Juste que lorsque c'est une feuille, toute la case et la ligne disparaissent ? Tu laisses tel quel quand ce n'est pas une feuille (devient grisé) ?

Comment: exactement :) c'est tout à fait ce dont j'ai besoin :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valentin,

I started by looking at the structure generated by the plugin you used, for example for the boss3:

```
<td colspan="2" class="node-container">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="node-cells">
                <td colspan="4" class="node-cell">
                    <div style="cursor: pointer;" class="node expanded">Boss 3</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <div class="line down"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="line left"></td>
                <td class="line right top"></td>
                <td class="line left top"></td>
                <td class="line right"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="node-container">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="node-cells">
                                <td colspan="2" class="node-cell">
                                    <div style="cursor: pointer;" class="node expanded">Richard</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <div class="line down"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="line left"></td>
                                <td class="line right"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" class="node-container">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr class="node-cells">
                                                <td colspan="2" class="node-cell">
                                                    <div class="node">Bizut</div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            <td colspan="2" class="node-container">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                            <tr class="node-cells">
                                <td colspan="2" class="node-cell">
                                    <div class="node">Nicolas</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>
```

So I just looked at the `removeNode` function to handle the different cases:

- If the selected item has siblings (other people at the same level), we just have to remove 2 lines: one `right top` and `left top` (see the table row with that kind of lines to understand) from the table row before the row of the selected item
- If the selected item does not have siblings, then you can drop the table row with those lines, but there will still remain a table row (the lines between shapes are made of 2 rows in order to handle the horizontal part of the lines), before this row, that's why I used my `containerUpperLineRow`

See function below:

```
function removeNode() {
    var parentContainer = lastClicked.closest('.node-container');
    var containerLowerLinesRow = parentContainer.parent().prev('tr');
    var containerUpperLineRow = containerLowerLinesRow.prev('tr');
    /* If item is a leaf, remove it and the lines */
    if (!lastClicked.hasClass("expanded")) {
        // Handle the lines going to the deleted item
        if (parentContainer.siblings().length > 0) {                
            // More than one remaining node at the same level: drop a "right top" and a "left top" line
            containerLowerLinesRow.children('.line.left.top:first').remove();
            containerLowerLinesRow.children('.line.right.top:first').remove();
            // Remove the selected item (from the node container)
            parentContainer.remove();
        } else {
            containerUpperLineRow.prev('tr').find('.expanded').removeClass('expanded');
            containerLowerLinesRow.remove();
            containerUpperLineRow.remove();
            // Remove the selected item (from the node container)
            parentContainer.remove();
            console.log("The node that we want to delete has no siblings");
        }
        console.log("We removed for real the node: " + lastClicked.html().trim().substring(0, 14));
    } else {
        /* If item is not a leaf, the node is desactivated, we put it in grey. */
        console.log("We desactived the node: " + lastClicked.html().trim().substring(0, 14));
        lastClicked.addClass("nodeDeleted").html(""); // And we erase the name of the node.
    }
}
```

Here is the fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/ndt02yjc/5/

Last edit handling the delete of an item which was not a leaf at first delete but which is a leaf at a further try

Comment: You couldn't do it better ! thank you very much :) that's exactly what I wanted ^^.
Now I just need to put the recursivity (because you know, a node without children becomes a leaf so it should be possible to delete it for real and not just put in grey :) ) 

But I will manage this part ;) thanks again !

Comment: It will be quite simple: I think you just have to remove the `expanded` class to the parent node when deleting an item that has no siblings (so it will be in the first `else` part of the function).

Comment: Ok I success to delete the "before-node and then leaf" but again, same problem with the blackline :P

I didn't succeed by your method to remove the "expanded" class in the first else... :/

http://jsfiddle.net/ndt02yjc/4/

Comment: We can discuss about it there: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59637/organisational-chart-debug